# Plotting CCDF of walking durations

Tags: r, ecdf

I have plotted the CCDF as mentioned in question part of the  [maximum plot points in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962954/maximum-plot-points-in-r) post to get a plot(image1) with this code:

```
ccdf<-function(duration,density=FALSE)
{
freqs = table(duration)
  X = rev(as.numeric(names(freqs)))
  Y =cumsum(rev(as.list(freqs)));
  data.frame(x=X,count=Y)
}
qplot(x,count,data=ccdf(duration),log='xy')
```

Now, on the basis of answer by [teucer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279497/teucer) on [Howto Plot “Reverse” Cumulative Frequency Graph With ECDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475511/howto-plot-reverse-cumulative-frequency-graph-with-ecdf)  I tried to plot a CCDF using the commands below:

```
f <- ecdf(duration)
plot(1-f(duration),duration)
```

I got a plot like image2.
Also I read in from the comments in one of the answers in [Plotting CDF of a dataset in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335227/plotting-cdf-of-a-dataset-in-r) as CCDF is nothing but 1-ECDF.
I am totally confused about how to get the CCDF of my data.

Image1
[image]

Image2[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generate some data and find the ecdf function.

```
x <- rlnorm(1e5, 5)
ecdf_x <- ecdf(x)
```

Generate vector at regular intervals over range of x.  (EDIT: you want them evenly spaced on a log scale in this case; if you have negative values, then use sample over a linear scale.)

```
xx <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 1e4)
#or
log_x <- log(x)
xx <- exp(seq(min(log_x), max(log_x), length.out = 1e3))
```

Create data with x and y coordinates for plot.

```
dfr <- data.frame(
  x = xx,
  ecdf = ecdf_x(xx),
  ccdf = 1 - ecdf_x(xx)
)
```

Draw plot.

```
p_ccdf <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, ccdf)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_log10()
p_ccdf
```

(Also take a look at `aes(x, ecdf)`.)

Comment: At the fourth step while generating interval vector xx shows NaN in all the elements. This happens after executing this command
xx <- exp(seq(min(log_x), max(log_x), length.out = 1e3))
Is it because of my data? A sample of my data stored in 'x' is given below<br/>
[99988,]           0 

[99989,]         132

[99990,]    19269015

[99991,]   724557277

[99992,]       86783

[99993,]     2407606

[99994,]    20955521

[99995,]        1337

[99996,]      172949

[99997,]     1179731

Comment: Moreover, it says: NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: If you have negative values, then taking logs makes no sense.  In that case, use the simpler call to `seq`.  It just made slightly more sense to define `xx` with even spacing on a log scale, since `x` came from a lognormal distribution.

Comment: I do not have negative values in my data and also my data x has not come from lognormal distribution. Is it still possible that I can still take the log scale? the problem is when calculation xx, taking log(x) is fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ritchie- I did not generate vector at regular intervals and just followed other steps:
<blink>
ecdf_x <- ecdf(x)
dfr <- data.frame(
   ecdf = ecdf_x(x),
  ccdf = 1 - ecdf_x(x)
)
p_ccdf <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, ccdf)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_log10()
p_ccdf
</blink>
And I think its okay. Now the only thing bothering me is to display fine scale marks on the axes

Answer (score 1):

I used ggplot to get desired ccdf plot of my data as shown below:

```
>>ecdf_x <- ecdf(x) 
>>dfr <- data.frame( ecdf = ecdf_x(x), 
>>ccdf = 1 - ecdf_x(x) ) 
>>p_ccdf <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, ccdf)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10() 
>>p_ccdf
```

Sorry for posting it so late.
Thank you all!