# how to draw ccdf in R with y axis showing probability

Tags: r

According to [Plotting CCDF of walking durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680635/plotting-ccdf-of-walking-durations),  I generated the ccdf plot like this:

```
ccdf<-function(views,density=FALSE)
  {
    freq = table(views)
    X = rev(as.numeric(names(freq)))
    Y =cumsum(rev(as.list(freq)));
    data.frame(x=X,count=Y)
  }
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,count,data=ccdf(views),log='xy')
```

[image: ccdf]

The Y axis = counts of x value, but I want to get the Y = P[X >= x], how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your data looks like but it sounds like you want:

```
ccdf<-function(views,density=FALSE)
  {
    freq = table(views)
    X = rev(as.numeric(names(freq)))
    Y =cumsum(as.list(freq));          #not reversed
    Y=(max(Y)-Y)/max(Y)                #proportion, beware recursion!
    data.frame(x=X,Cum.Prop=Y)         #name change  
  }
qplot(x,Cum.Prop ,data=ccdf(views),log='xy')
```

If you tell me a bit more about your `views` variable I can make sure that it is working right.